# Does ConcurrentHashMap need synchronization when incrementing its values?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization, locks

I know ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe e.g.putIfAbsent,Replace etc., but I was wondering, is a block of code like the one below safe?

```
if (accumulator.containsKey(key)) { //accumulator is a ConcurrentHashMap
    accumulator.put(key, accumulator.get(key)+1); 
} else {
    accumulator.put(key, 0); 
}
```

Keep in mind that the accumulator value for a key may be asked by two different threads simultaneously, which would cause a problem in a normal HashMap. So do I need something like this?

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,Object> locks;
...
locks.putIfAbsent(key,new Object());
synchronized(locks.get(key)) {
    if (accumulator.containsKey(key)) { 
        accumulator.put(key, accumulator.get(key)+1); 
    } else {
        accumulator.put(key, 0); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (accumulator.containsKey(key)) { //accumulator is a ConcurrentHashMap
    accumulator.put(key, accumulator.get(key)+1); 
} else {
    accumulator.put(key, 0); 
}
```

No, this code is not thread-safe; `accumulator.get(key)` can be changed in between the `get` and the `put`, or the entry can be added between the `containsKey` and the `put`.  If you're in Java 8, you can write `accumulator.compute(key, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 0 : v + 1)`, or any of the many equivalents, and it'll work.  If you're not, the thing to do is write something like

```
while (true) {
  Integer old = accumulator.get(key);
  if (old == null) {
    if (accumulator.putIfAbsent(key, 0) == null) {
      // note: it's a little surprising that you want to put 0 in this case,
      // are you sure you don't mean 1?
      break;
    }
  } else if (accumulator.replace(key, old, old + 1)) {
    break;
  }
}
```

...which loops until it manages to make the atomic swap.  This sort of loop is pretty much how you *have* to do it: it's how `AtomicInteger` works, and what you're asking for is `AtomicInteger` across many keys.

Alternately, you can use a library: e.g. Guava has `AtomicLongMap` and `ConcurrentHashMultiset`, which also do things like this.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'll take the Java 8 approach! Much clearer!
By the way, is my second approach Thread-safe? Just out of curiosity!

Comment: @Sofia note that it's a little weird to be putting in 0 in the absent case instead of 1, and if you _did_ mean 1, it might be arguably a little clearer to write `accumulator.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: @Sofia your second approach...probably works, but it's really awkward and inefficient, because you're introducing a second `ConcurrentHashMap` where filling it out just happens to be easier to make thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, the 0 was hypothetical. In reality I'm putting TF*IDF weights. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you would be to use an `AtomicInteger`. The nice feature here is that it is non-blocking, mutable and thread-safe. You can use the `replace` method offered by the CHM, but with that you will have to hold a lock of the segment/bucket-entry prior to the replace completing.

With the `AtomicInteger` you leverage quick non-blocking updates.

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, AtomicInteger> map;
```

then

```
map.get(key).incrementAndGet();
```

---

If you are using Java 8, `LongAdder` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that your first code snippet is unsafe. It's totally reasonable for the thread to get interrupted right after the check has been performed and for another thread to begin executing. Therefore in the first snippet the following could happen:

```
[Thread 1]: Check for key, return false
[Thread 2]: Check for key, return false
[Thread 2]: Put value 0 in for key
[Thread 1]: Put value 0 in for key
```

In this example, the behavior you would want would leave you in a state with the value for that key being set to 1, not 0.

Therefore locking is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Only individual actions on ConcurrentHashMap are thread-safe; taking multiple actions in sequence is not. Your first block of code is not thread-safe. It is possible, for example:

```
THREAD A: accumulator.containsKey(key) = false
THREAD B: accumulator.containsKey(key) = false
THREAD B: accumulator.put(key, 0)
THREAD A: accumulator.put(key, 0)
```

Similary, it is not thread-safe to get the accumulator value for a given key, increment it, and then put it back in the map. This is a three-step process, and it is possible for another thread to interrupt at any point.

Your second synchronized block of code is thread-safe.