# I'm trying to increment value for ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

All with multi-threaded programming and without Guava.
My problem is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373144/does-concurrenthashmap-need-synchronization-when-incrementing-its-values), but i want to solve it without `break;`. I have already read this topic, but still didn't resolve problem, I newborn in multi-threaded, so perhaps the solution is here, but I can not see it.

I'm trying to count words. If this word already met, just increment value, if is not, just put new node into map with key `word` and `value` 1.

This my code, and it is wrong. I want to avoid any loops.

```
String word = m.group();
if(wordMap.putIfAbsent(word, 1) == null){
    Integer old;
    while (!wordMap.replace(word, old = wordMap.get(word), old + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge-Method is what you're most likely looking for:

```
String word = m.group();
wordMap.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373144/does-concurrenthashmap-need-synchronization-when-incrementing-its-values) that you have quoted earlier, already has the optimal solution.

You can use Java 8 features of computeIfPresent() and putIfAbsent() as they do handle concurrency.
ConcurrentMap handles memory consistency on key/value operations in a multi-threaded environment.

As per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.

Comment: But if I will use computeIfPresent() and putIfAbsent() in same time, it will make excess verification. I want to make one verification and proceed from this result with one of instructions.

Comment: In that case you can use compute() as follows:
wordMap.compute(word,(k,v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : v + 1);
As per your requirement, this will add new entry if your word doesn't have an occurrence in your map, or increment the value if it exists

Comment: But when you use it like 2 instructions without sync (or smth like this) it is turning to non-atomic.

Comment: Yes, as per documentation, any attempted update operations on the particular map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, my point is, the threads are blocked till the computation is performed, but that doesn't make it non-atomic completely.
I agree that a simpler implementation would be to implement the solution provided by @codeflush.dev